# How to Host WCF Service dynamically

Tags: c#, wcf, dynamic

I have a wsdl of existing service, I am able to fetch service contract and its implementation class from wsdl along with configurations, now I want to create mock service to host in WCF self hosting. The servicehost should be generic to host any wcf service generated from existing wsdl. I'm using C# for it.

Or if there is another solution to host wcf service dynamically irrespective of service contract provided, please help. Thank you!